# Is gazebo -p of state log normally 1/20th of real time speed?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We're trying to validate the qualification log for DRCSim, and the gazebo -p playback is taking an extremely long time.
We've taken over 30 minutes to replay 1:21 of simulation time, which corresponds to 3:17 of real wall clock time.

Is this normal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2805/is-gazebo--p-of-state-log-normally-1/20th-of-real-time-speed?/) by [Felipe Bacim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/135/felipe-bacim/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We had some roscode running that was trying to talk with gazebo on restart.  That slowing things down.  Killing all processes on all computers first allowed gazebo to run at normal speed.

---

Originally posted by [Felipe Bacim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/135/felipe-bacim/) with karma: 16 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0